# Intellij IDEA 2017.1.1 - How to display multiple console tabs?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 2017.1.1

I run multiple clones of same project and I need easy visibility of all console windows. How can I do it?

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhrR9.png)

Comment: If you drag the tab outside of the intelliJ window, they become independent 'floating' windows...

Comment: @ochi, I'm sorry, I meant the 'run' tab. I can't drag it. All I can do is to right click on it and switch to floating mode which applies to whole 'run' tab.

Comment: When you start app1, you should be able to 'pin' the output window... when you run app2 you can drag the output tab (and see it in floating mode) - is that what you mean?

Comment: I seem to be able to float tabs from the 'debug' window but not the 'run' window :(

Comment: @ochi, Thank you. I checked debug window and it worked, not exactly as I wanted to but that's something at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking in the title bar and select `Split Mode`.

[image]

Comment: sadly, this does not allow you to see multiple outputs, only moves the 'run' window to the bottom right so that you can have it open while your view other stuff on the bottom left (terminal?) - but all 'run' tabs will show on the right half of the split window